# SWIFT: Display single value from remote JSON file in UI Label

Tags: ios, json, swift

Im trying to create a small and simple app.

- iOS
- Reads single value from remote JSON file (ie a true/false)
- Displays the value in a UI label on screen

This is the initial idea...but I eventually hope to read the value, and depending on whether true or false...perform some other functionality.

At this stage, just want to read and display it on screen.

Here is what I have so far and it works as far as printing to the log, but not to the screen/UILabel which is my goal.

```
import UIKit

struct DemoData: Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        
        
        let urlString = "https://subdomain.domain.com/json/myData.json"
        self.loadJson(fromURLString: urlString) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                self.parse(jsonData: data)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        
        let labelRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        let label = UILabel(frame: labelRect)
        label.text = "Description should be here"
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    private func loadJson(fromURLString urlString: String,
                          completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    completion(.success(data))
                }
            }
            
            urlSession.resume()
        }
    }

    private func parse(jsonData: Data) {
        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(DemoData.self,
                                                       from: jsonData)
            
            print("Title: ", decodedData.title)
            print("Description: ", decodedData.description)
            print("===================================")
        } catch {
            print("decode error")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON file that is hosted remotely...it will just say true or false, this is what Im using to get it working.

```
{
    "title": "Remote file",
    "description": "This is text from the remote JSON file"
}
```

Its not pretty, but Im hoping to solve small things as I move on with my idea....any help I would be extremely grateful.

Many thanks everyone :)

Comment: If I understand, the label should be a property of the view controller so you can update it upon successfull download. But you did not ask any question.

Comment: @PtitXav the question was inferred in the introduction. As in...this is what Im trying to achieve, and it is currently not working. Apologies if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declare the label lazily on the top level of the view controller to have a reference

```
lazy var label : UILabel = {
    let labelRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
    let uiLabel = UILabel(frame: labelRect)
    uiLabel.text = "Description should be here"
    uiLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    return uiLabel 
}()
```

then assign the value after the line to print the description in `parse`

```
...
    print("===================================")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = decodedData.description
    }
} catch { ...
```

Comment: Hey @vadian thanks for replying. I tried this and got the following error...does that mean anything to you...

Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel initWithFrame:]

Cheers
Simon

Comment: Please see the edit. You have to assign the value on the main thread.

Comment: Thankyou again @vadian, getting close I think...its not giving an error which is amazing. 
The only thing is it isnt appearing on the simulator screen at all. Any thoughts? 

Cheers
Simon

Comment: Of course you still have to add the label as a subview (or use an outlet).

Comment: Oh my goodness...of course...thankyou @vadian...that was perfect. Thankyou so much, really appreciate you helping me out. Cheers, simon

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're creating the label within the scope of `viewDidLoad()`. The value from the JSON response won't be available yet, since it is asynchronously fetched.

If you make the label a class property instead and set its text to `decodedData.title` in the same place where you're currently printing out the value, it should populate correctly.

```
let label = UILabel()

private func parse(jsonData: Data) {
    do {
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(DemoData.self,
                                                   from: jsonData)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.label.text = decodedData.title
        }

        print("Title: ", decodedData.title)
        print("Description: ", decodedData.description)
        print("===================================")
    } catch {
        print("decode error")
    }
}
```

P.S.: make sure you add `[weak self]` at the beginning of your `loadJson(fromURLString: urlString)` completion block in `viewDidLoad()` to avoid trying to access self after it's been deallocated :)

Comment: Thank you for replying @mimo ...just trying this now...but getting the following message, which I kind of understand but not sure how to  correct.

Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:]

Also, afraid Im not sure about the [weak self] you mentioned.

Cheers, Simon